# Proof about Finite set (Surjectivity and Injectivity)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $B$ be a non-empty set. Then the following are equivalent:

(1) $B$ is finite.

(2) There is a surjective funtion $f:\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow B$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

(3) There is an injective function $g:B \rightarrow \{1,...,n\}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$

My attempt:

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2)

Since, $B$ is a non-empty finite set, there exists a bijective function $h:B \rightarrow \{1,...,n\} $ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

So, there exists a bijective inverse function $h^{-1}:\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow B$. for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

$\therefore$ There exists a surjective function $f:\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow B$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

I'm not sure if my above proof is valid. 
Also, can someone please help me with the proofs for (2)$\Rightarrow$ (3) and (3)$\Rightarrow$ (1) ??

Comment: This has nothing what so ever to do with either [tag:real-analysis] or [tag:finite-fields]. Please check the relevant tag wiki excerpts for information before using a tag you are unfamiliar with. Guessing is very likely to go wrong, because natural language terms often have a technical meaning in math.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems ok. For the others

(2) => (3)

Let $f$ be your surjection $\{1,\dots,n\} \to B$.

Define $g$ as $$g(b) = \min \{i \in \{1,\dots,n\} \mid f(i) = b\}.$$ This is well defined because $f$ is surjective, hence the set is never empty, and always finite.

Then, let $x,y\in B$ such that $g(x) = g(y)$.
By definition, $f(g(x)) = x$ and $f(g(y)) = y$, and $f(g(x)) = f (g(y)$, thus $x=y$.

(3) => (1)

Let $g$ be your injection $B\to \{1,\dots,n\}$. Then $h:B \to Im(g)$ defined by $h(x) = g(x)$ is a bijection, and $Im(g) \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}$ which is finite.You have then a bijection between $B$ and a finite set, thus $B$ is finite.